# How can I show the maximum score of each department with their names

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I can select maximum the score of each department but I can't show the name of each person associated with the max score.
I tried to select the name and the maximum grade (with maximum function) but it doesn't work:

```
select max(stgrade)as highscore,StName,DepName --department
from TBL_DEPARTMANTS d
inner join TBL_LESSONS l on d.DepID=l.LessonID
inner join TBL_GRADES g on g.lessonid=l.LessonID
inner join TBL_STUDENT s on s.STID=g.stid
group by DepName,StName
order by DepName,highscore desc
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample date of each tables ? Is the join correct between TBL_DEPARTMENTS and TBL_LESSONS ?

Comment: for each `department` which `name` do you want to show ? Is that a working query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always hard to do theory selects, but while DarkRob's solution is good, it will remove students if for instance two people are best. This is why I love using cross apply:

```
select
      d.Depname
    , s.StName
    , g.stgrade
from TBL_DEPARTMANTS d
inner join TBL_LESSONS l on
    d.DepID=l.LessonID
inner join TBL_GRADES g on
    g.lessonid=l.LessonID
inner join TBL_STUDENT s on
    s.STID=g.stid
cross apply (
    select
          sub_d.DepID
        , max(sub_g.stgrade) as maxgrade
    from TBL_DEPARTMANTS sub_d
    inner join TBL_LESSONS sub_l on
        sub_d.DepID=sub_l.LessonID
    inner join TBL_GRADES sub_g on
        sub_g.lessonid=sub_l.LessonID
    where sub_d.Dep_ID = d.Dep_ID
    group by sub_d.DepID
) as sub 
where g.stgrade = sub.maxgrade
```

This way you will get all the people with max grade per department and not just one.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this...

```
select * from ( select rank() over (partition by DepName order by stgrade desc) as Slno, stgrade, stname, DepName 
from TBL_DEPARTMANTS d
inner join TBL_LESSONS l on d.DepID=l.LessonID
inner join TBL_GRADES g on g.lessonid=l.LessonID
inner join TBL_STUDENT s on s.STID=g.stid  ) as dep where dep.slno=1
```

First create `rank()` in decreasing order of grade for individual department. then select top record for same.

Note: Use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`, both will work fine for top 1 record, while if you want to select `n` highest grade then use `DENSE_RANK()`, at the last for `slno` pass `n'th` record you want to select.

Comment: i just sign in and cant mark it  ==>Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: @fast: for case mentioned by @philippe you can use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`. Updated my ans please check.